# Adding Ransack Gem with Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I am displaying a list of gyms, and users can view gyms by province. I would like to add search capability using the Ransack gem, but I am not sure how to go about it with my current set up. Looking for some advice.

Gyms controller

```
def index

    if params[:province].blank?
        @gyms=Gym.all.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
        else
        @province_id = Province.find_by(name: params[:province]).id
        @gyms = Gym.where(province_id: @province_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
        end

    end
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just replaced my existing controller code with this:

```
@q = Gym.ransack(params[:q]) 
@gyms = @q.result.includes(:province).page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
```